# jQuery works until I action another script?

Tags: jquery, css, conflict, css-transitions

I have made a page under

http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~staged2b/about/staff

As you can see the filters between staff members work but as soon as you switch to a new staff group the roll over pop outs don't work.

These are the two scripts in the head there to much to past, but I have some css which makes the image with class hover pop out when rolled over.

I been trying to fix this for days any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kindest Regards
Brent French

Comment: there clearly is a JavaScript error.

Comment: I cant seem to work out how to fix it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgHover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the problem. Change the above to:

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgHover")
        .live('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.85).end().children(".hover").show();
        })
        .live('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

You are unbinding the function when you change the staff group. Using `.live()` will keep the event bound. Ideally you would use `.delegate()` but that is only available in a later version of jQuery

**More information:**

1. [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
2. [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
3. [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

**EDIT**

Just noticed the `.delegate()` is actually present in 1.4.2; I thought it came in later. I would recommend changing from `.live()` to `.delegate()` because you can attach the event listener to a parent element (one that isn't changed by the other script). Check the link to the docs (above) for the change in syntax

Comment: please please please, remove the `live()` and replace it with `on()`. `Live()` is deprecated

Comment: Removed previous comment which was incorrect. I got confused and thought `.delegate()` appeared in a later version (OP is using 1.4.2 which precludes `.on()`). Updated my answer accordingly.